# The difference between SELECT * and SELECT A.*

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am new to SQL can someone help me understand why do we use Select .* in sql server ? And why is it different from just select * from table name
In some cases we use statements like select .*, firstname , lastname from employee. Just a bit confused.

Comment: I have never seen `select .*`  used in a query.

Comment: Not valid syntax http://rextester.com/BPYXD59851

Comment: I use it when I want to see the Invalid column prefix '': No table name specified error

Comment: Just for kicks and giggles, I put the `SELECT .*` into SQL Server and it gave me `Invalid column prefix '': No table name specified` - you _can_, however, use a table alias so that it's `SELECT a.*, [column list from table b]` with a proper JOIN.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

.* means, select all columns of a table

`SELECT A.*,B.Id from A,B` select all columns of A and only Id column of B.

Comment: Hi selami , thank you for your response. Its there just because u cannot use a select * when selecting from multiple tables basically ?

Comment: You can use SELECT * on multiple tables, you just get all columns of all tables then.